# chosen.js hide remove (X) from already selected options but keep for new options

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I have one custom requirement in my project which I want to share with you.

I have used this awesome JavaScript library called [jquery-chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) and this works well.

I have multiple selection drop-down box called as "Category" in edit profile page. Now when the page loads, this drop-down will have few already selected categories in the list.

Now what I want is, I should not be able to remove the already selected by clicking on Remove (X). But at the same time, I should be able to add new and when I add new, I should be able to see Remove (X) button because I haven't updated my page.

I went through their documentation and did some research on stackoverflow as well but so far I haven't found any proper solution to achieve this. Hence I have come up with a question ( So no code yet to show :( ). Hope this makes sense.

Can anyone guide me to accomplish this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by _I should not be able to remove the already selected by clicking on Remove (X). But at the same time, I should be able to add new and when I add new, I should be able to see Remove (X) button because I haven't updated my page._ without an example

Comment: So please update your question with that explanation and html example of existing and added data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every selected element after loaded will look like this:

```
<li class=search-choice>
         <span> text of selected item </span>
        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
</li>
```

I suggest after loading you go over already selected items and place display:none style for an 'a' element, which is actually your 'X' for removal.